# Running curl GET request in java gives exit code 3

Tags: java, macos, shell, api, curl

When i run the following command on my shell it gives out the expected JSon output (I'm using macOS).

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic MYKEY’ -i 'http://MYAPI’ --data ‘MYBODY’
```

But if i do the same thing using Java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec (code below) it just returns a exit code 3 (Malformed URL, according to the CURL docs).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

void runCommand("curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic MYKEY’ -i ‘http://MYAPI’ --data ‘MYBODY’”) {

    String s;
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line: " + s);
        }
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exit: " + p.exitValue());
        p.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
}
```

I tried using the same code to run curl on HTML pages (google.com), which works perfectly. What am i doing wrong here? 
Please note there are restrictions on the API server which forced me to use curl on command line rather than calling it through a library. Thanks so much for any ideas.

Comment: Try putting your arguments into a string array and calling `exec("curl", args)` instead.

Comment: @lexicore Worked like a charm. Thanks so much

Comment: @lexicore Can you please explain how this is different and why it works? I tried your suggestion but `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` second parameter is supposed to be environnement variables, according to [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec\(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]\))